# Merging multiple rows according to an order

Tags: sql, psql

Suppose there are the following rows

```
| Id | MachineName | WorkerName | MachineState |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Alpha       | Young      |  RUNNING     |
| 1  | Beta        |            |  STOPPED     |
| 1  | Gamma       | Foo        |  READY       |
| 1  | Zeta        | Zatta      |              |
| 2  | Guu         | Niim       |  RUNNING     |
| 2  | Yuu         | Jaam       |  STOPPED     |
| 2  | Nuu         |            |  READY       |
| 2  | Faah        | Siim       |              |
| 3  | Iem         |            |  RUNNING     |
| 3  | Nyt         | Fish       |  READY       |
| 3  | Qwe         | Siim       |              |
```

We want to merge these rows according to following priority :

STOPPED > RUNNING > READY > (null or empty)

If a row has a value for greatest priority, then value from that row should be used (only if it is not null). If it is null, a value from any other row should be used. The rows should be grouped by id

The correct output for the above input is :

```
| Id | MachineName | WorkerName | MachineState |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Beta        | Foo        |  STOPPED     |
| 2  | Yuu         | Jaam       |  STOPPED     |
| 3  | Iem         | Fish       |  RUNNING     |
```

What would be a good sql query to accomplish this? I tried using joins, but it did not work out.

Comment: Can you show what was your query?

Comment: Which record(s) do you want in the resultset if/when there are multiple records with the maximal `(Id,MachineState)` combination?

Comment: @eggyal There will never be such a case.

Comment: Your problem indicates poor schema design.  If `WorkerName` is not genuinely a property of the row in which it is held (e.g. the value you want for `WorkerName` when retrieving a row may actually be that from some other row) then it doesn't really belong there.  You should consider redesigning the schema to better reflect the semantics of your business problem.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that this question is tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:psql] which are competing RDBMS products from different vendors.  Which are you actually using?

Comment: I am using psql. It got tagged mysql accidentally. Removed that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view this as a case of the group-wise maximum problem, provided you can obtain a suitable ordering over your `MachineState` column—e.g. by using a [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression:

```
SELECT   a.Id,
         COALESCE(a.MachineName, t.MachineName) MachineName,
         COALESCE(a.WorkerName , t.WorkerName ) WorkerName,
         a.MachineState
FROM     myTable a JOIN (
           SELECT   Id,
                    MIN(MachineName) AS MachineName,
                    MIN(WorkerName ) AS WorkerName,
                    MAX(CASE MachineState
                      WHEN 'READY'   THEN 1
                      WHEN 'RUNNING' THEN 2
                      WHEN 'STOPPED' THEN 3
                    END) AS MachineState
           FROM     myTable
           GROUP BY Id
         ) t ON t.Id = a.Id AND t.MachineState = CASE a.MachineState
           WHEN 'READY'   THEN 1
           WHEN 'RUNNING' THEN 2
           WHEN 'STOPPED' THEN 3
         END
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ca10/2/0):

```
| id | machinename | workername | machinestate |
|----|-------------|------------|--------------|
|  1 |        Beta |        Foo |      STOPPED |
|  2 |         Yuu |       Jaam |      STOPPED |
|  3 |         Iem |       Fish |      RUNNING |
```

You could save yourself the pain of using `CASE` if `MachineState` was an [`ENUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) type column (defined in the appropriate order).  It so happens in this case that a simple lexicographic ordering over the string value will yield the same result, but that's a coincidence on which you really shouldn't rely as it's bound to slip under the radar when someone tries to maintain this code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prioritization query.  One method uses variables.  Another uses `union all` . . . this works if the states are not repeated for a given id:

```
select t.*
from table t
where machinestate = 'STOPPED'
union all
select t.*
from table t
where machinestate = 'RUNNING' and
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.machinestate in ('STOPPED'))
union all
select t.*
from table t
where machinestate = 'READY' and
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.machinestate in ('STOPPED', 'RUNNING'));
```

Answer (score 0):

change MachineState as enum:

```
`MachineState` enum('READY','RUNNING','STOPPED') DEFAULT NULL
```

and sql is simple:

```
select t.id,state.machinename,state.workername,t.mstate from state,(select id,max(MachineState) mstate from state group by Id) t  where t.mstate=state.machinestate and t.id=state.id;
```